# Castle Project ActiveRecord with XML

Tags: castle-activerecord

Can Castle ActiveRecord write to XML document? Any links to sample code?

Answer (score 1):

Castle ActiveRecord is using NHibernate underneath. As far as I know, there is no XML-database driver for NHibernate.

So, answering your question - no, currently Castle ActiveRecord can't do this. If somebody writes a driver for XML file database - it could. Not a trivial task. I wonder if it is possible at all...

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [this OLE DB Provider for XML](http://www.viksoe.dk/code/xmloledb.htm), but I wouldn't count on it supporting all of NHibernate features and it will be limited in the schemas it can understand. Plus, you'd have to play a bit with dialect settings to see which one fits best.